# PHP Mysql Query in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have two table one is "forum_topic" and second is "forum_comments"

I want a CodeIgniter Query to get a forum_topic detail, for example i have a query "select * from forum_topic where topic_id = 1" then i want all the comments from forum_comments table based on "forum_comments.topic_id = forum_topic.topic_id", but forum comments should be in tree view format because we also have n-level replies for every comment that are also store in "forum_comments" table, you can see in forum_comments table there is a field "parent" that holds "comment_id" for which the reply made.

**1 - forum_topic**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `forum_topic` (
  `topic_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `category` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `content` text NOT NULL,
  `created_by` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `view_count` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `last_activity` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `status` enum('publish','unpublish') NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`topic_id`)
)
```

**2 - forum_comments**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `forum_comments` (
  `comment_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `comment_by` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `topic_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `parent` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `comment` text NOT NULL,
  `commented_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `commented_type` enum('user','admin') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'user',
  `status` enum('publish','unpublish','block') NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`comment_id`)
```

)

Comment: What you have tried..??

Comment: i tried with custom code, fire multiple queries

Comment: So you just need comments based on topic id from forum topic?

Comment: please post some sample data and expected output,

Comment: yes, i want only one help, how to get comments based on topic id in tree format, i can use two queries one is for forum_topic and second is for all comments

Comment: You got so many answers on your question. Can you bother replying that which one helped you, or someone's answer helped you or not? Don't you think you should reply if someone is trying to help you?

Comment: @GarryCuston whenever you think you have found an answer you should accept it. So other people are not bothered to see your question repeatedly

Comment: No, problem is still exist, just tried custom code for time being.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for efficiency over lots of loops or joins, I'd say use the "left and right tree" format for the 'forum_comments' table:

http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database-2/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model

Comment: i want only one help, how to get comments based on topic id in tree format, i can use two queries one is for forum_topic and second is for all comments

Comment: Easy, add the columns (left, right, depth) to your forum_comments, then simply SELECT * FROM forum_comments WHERE topic_id = $topic_id ORDER BY left ASC. That IS your tree. If you don't want to do the readings then there's nothing I can do to help. The first article tells you exactly what to do to update/delete items, and with a little practice (not included in article) you can even move sub-trees around based on the left and right. The depth is not required but makes your layout easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a model function like this with query

```
function getComments($topic_id){
    $query  =   "   SELECT
                        fc.*
                    FROM forum_topic AS ft
                    INNER JOIN forum_comments AS fc ON ft.topic_id  =   fc.topic_id
                    WHERE ft.topic_id   =   $topic_id
                    ORDER BY fc.parent";
    return $this->db->query($query)->result();
}
```

Comment: Thanks raheel, i think this can help me. i am trying to use your solution.

Comment: Thank you Dead Man, i am applying the possible solutions that you guys sent

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query and see if it works:

```
Select top.*,com.* from forum_topic as top left join forum_comments as com on com.topic_id = top.topic_id where top.topic_id = 1 order by top.topic_id desc
```